# Why send token in header when you can send it in post?

Tags: php, jwt, http-headers, token, bearer-token

Im building restful api and im using firebase/php-jwt for my authentication
and currently what im doing for Receiving token from client like this :

```php
if(isset($_POST['token'])){
//do something
}
```

and sending it like this (so then client can access the token through the json response):

```php
echo json_encode([
'token'=>$token,
'status'=>[
   'error'=>false,
   'msg'=>'token created successfully'
 ]

]);
```

but i seen lots of programmer sending token like this

```php
header("Authorization: Bearer $token");
```

and Receiving the token from client request like this :

```php
$headers = apache_request_headers();//assuming that we are using apache as webserver
$token = $headers['token'];
```

my main question is whats the difference ? is there any security or performance differences ?
which one is better practice ?

sorry for my bad english

Comment: This is somewhat opinion based. I'd say it's neater to put the token in the header because it authenticates the whole request, and that happens for every request, and it's not actually part of the data you're sending for this individual specific request. That's my view about it, and I know many APIs do it like that, but there are no rules and no "best" approach, so you may find others disagree. You should do whatever you think makes the most sense for your application.

Comment: As @ADyson said, it is more of a convention and the authentication or authorization is kept separate from the actual request body.

Comment: so its just convention and doesnt affect anything? like performance or security and etc...

Comment: When authenticating requests with the token, it is a bit easier to set a global header for all requests  when using a front-end AJAX library like Axios and you don't have to worry about messing up the POST data format or add the token manually with every request. When giving out tokens, I do both, set an Authorization header and send it in the response body.

Comment: thank you all guys i appreciate the comments :)

Comment: if you have a GET-request, there's no request body in which you could send a token. And I would generally separate things, using the body only for the actual task (business logic).

Comment: I wouldn't advocate this, but sending the token in the request body can be a way to work around CORS issues. As soon as you send a request with an "Authorization" header, it is no longer a ["simple request"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests) and browsers will issue a preflight request first. This requires correct CORS configuration on the server, whereas for "simple" POST requests where the token is in the request body, no preflight request is sent and the actual request will probably work even if CORS is not/incorrectly configured on the server.

Comment: Hi, Actually, it's more than a convention. The Authorization header is usually not logged at all while query strings, and potentially request body, are.
Please refer to the [RFC6819 section-5.4.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6819#section-5.4.1). In addition and as mentioned hereabove, you can send access token through the header whatever the verb is : GET, POST, OPTION, PUT, PATCH, DELETE...